# 'Would have' used alone for unreal past situations, not in conditional

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, infinitives

Can I use *would have* alone like

> The situation would have been worse without his help.
>
> The lack of anybody's cooperation would have caused us a lot of problems.

to provide the same meaning as using the third conditional (unreal **past** situations) like

> The situation would have been worse if he hadn't helped us.

?

I've seen this use with other modal auxiliary verbs such as *could have, must have* in a grammar book. But I couldn't seem to find *would have* used alone in the book. So I would like to ensure if this is the correct use of perfect infinitives. Detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Fantaiser, this is an intersting question, +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable.

Both your sentences present conditionals; although they are not expressed as formal *IF ... THEN* constructions, they might easily be so:

> The situation would have been worse ***if*** he hadn't helped.
>   It would have caused us a lot of problems ***if*** anybody had not cooperated.

The protasis (*IF* clause) of a conditional may lie outside the sentence at hand; this does not invalidate the use of *would*:

> It looked like the school might have to close. That would have been a shame. = *If the school had had to close, it would have been a shame.*

All of these uses are equally valid with non-past<sup>**✲**</sup> reference:

> The situation would be worse without his help.
>   The lack of anybody's cooperation would cause us a lot of problems.
>   It looks like the school may have to close. That would be a shame.

In fact, most uses of *would* may be understood as implicitly conditional, though the actual condition implied may be very vague:

> I would like a piece of pie. [eg, *if you have any* or *if you would be so kind as to bring me one*]
>   I would be happy to do that for you. [eg, *if you were to ask me* or *if you need help*]
>   I would never say such a thing! [eg, *if the opportunity arose* or *even if I were provoked*]

---

<sup>**✲**</sup> I should perhaps note that *past modal* + *have* + *past participle* , although it **looks** like a “perfect” construction, has nothing to do with the ordinary English “perfect”. It is, rather, the language’s workaround for the awkward fact that the modals *can*, *may*, *shall*, *will* may be used in their “past” forms with non-past (present or future) reference—which leaves them no convenient form for expressing the same modality with **past** reference. To accomplish that, we employ the “perfect” construction. *It would have been* is in effect the **simple past** of *It would be*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing everything out! I've already known that it has nothing to do with the _perfect_ (as in _perfect tense_), and it's just in the _perfect_ form. Thanks anyway for the note!

Comment: @Fantaiser I sorta suspected you did; but you referred to the "perfect infinitive"; and lots of readers won't know about this; so I stuck it in.