# How can we put these time orders?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense

> She could not follow the ugly academic jargon, that rattled itself off
>   so glibly, but said to herself that she saw now why going to the
>   circus had knocked him off his perch, poor little man, and why he came
>   out, instantly, with all that about his father and mother and brothers
>   and sisters, and she would see to it that they didn't laugh at him any
>   more; she would tell Prue about it. What he would have liked(1), she
>   supposed(2), would have been to say(3) how he had gone(4) not to the
>   circus but to Ibsen with the Ramsays. He was an awful prig –– oh yes,
>   an insufferable bore.  
> (Virginia Woolf, To the Lighthouse)

What’s the time orders between (1), (2), (3), and (4)?

When I consulting the reference time (2), it seems (4) < (1) < (3). But I think there’s no need to have perfect tense in “What he would have liked.” This is confusing me.

Comment: Neither of those *have*s is perfect. They are both pasts of modal-present *would* - see the footnote at [http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/6313/32]

Comment: You cannot say "time orders among". *Among* is not correctly used in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is a valid re-wording of the sentence in question:

> She supposed (2) that he would have liked (1) to say (3) how he had gone (4) [...]

This hopefully makes it slightly less opaque that all the other events are prior to reference time (2), and go in the order of 4-> (1/3) -> 2; that is, at time N, he went to Ibsen; at time N+1, he (probably) wanted to say something about it; at time (N+2) she supposed that he had wanted to say something about it at time N+1.

I don't see how you can escape the use of "would have liked", though, even after rearranging the sentence.